# How to detect if someone is hit by something with a custom model data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I'm trying to make a data pack with custom items in it but I can't figure out how to detect if someone is hit by an item with a Custom Model Data. I have tried using an advancement, but it seems to make it so whenever I hit someone in general, not just with a stick.

If somebody could find out what's going on I'll be pretty thankful, even if they can't make it for only a stick with a custom model data.

This is the advancement I have currently:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It's better if you paste your code, and not a screenshot of it

Answer (score 1):

Something to the effect of this?

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "requirement": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:entity_hurt_player",
      "conditions": {
        "damage": {
          "source_entity": {
            "type": "minecraft:player",
            "nbt": "{CustomModelData:101}",
            "team": "Yo"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the player requirement means it only works if you are hit by a player. If you want it to work for mobs too, you can remove that requirement.

I think putting your custom model nbt in the nbt requirement should make it work, but if not you can also have a separate command running to execute as all players holding an item matching that nbt (which I can paste if you need it) and have them join a team. The team check would also trigger when anyone on that team hits you.